# Differentiating between Accept and Delete Notifications from Microsoft Graph Events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I created a subscription to my Outlook calendar using the Microsoft graph SDK.

When I accept an event in Outlook, Outlook sends my server 3 notifications in succession:

1. Event Updated
2. Event Delete
3. Event Created

As far as I can tell, this means Outlook is:

1. Registering that the event has changed
2. Deleting the current instance of the event
3. Creating a brand new accepted event (with the same ICalUId as the deleted event)

When I look at the notifications sent by Outlook, the first two notifications (update and delete) have the same event id but the create notification has a different event id.

Is there any way to differentiate between the delete notification coming from this batch of notifications  (after someone clicks "Accept") and the delete notification sent to me when an event is actually declined/removed from Outlook?

NOTE- Currently I am storing the iCalUId for the event in my database and when I receive a deleted notification, I get the iCalUId for the event and check Outlook to see if an event with the same ICalUId exists. If there is an event, I update my db and don't delete the event. However, this morning I noticed that it took Outlook nearly 10 seconds to go from steps 2 to 3 (deleting the instance to creating a new instance).

More specifically, I received the deleted notification, checked Outlook to see if an event with the same ICalUId was there and there was none. 10 seconds later (after I deleted the event from my db) I received an event created notification.

The only potential work-around I can think of is to continue checking for the event in Outlook for a period of time (30 seconds?).

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can implement that workaround.